# Checkbox inputs selected based on data from mysql table

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I’m working with two tables:
**Videogames** with the videogames list and **videojuegos_tienen_usuarios** with the videogames selected by the users.
What I want is to display the videogames list like in the Image below, the select inputs show all the videogames available and the checked boxes are the videogames that the user already selected.
Also, the user should be able to edit the videogames selecting new ones or removing the games he/she already selected. I tried with the code below but I'm not getting any result.

thanks in advance

[image]

**Table: videojuegos_tienen_usuarios**

[image]

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function editGamesUser(int $id)
{
$user = Usuario::findOrFail($id);

return view('admin.videojuegos.usuarios', [
user => $user,
]);
}
public function editExecuteGamesUsers(Request $request, int $id)
{
$request->validate(User::VALIDATE_RULES, User::VALIDATE_MESSAGES);

$user = User::findOrFail($id);

$data = $request->except(['_token']);

try {
DB::transaction(function() use ($user, $data) {
$user->update($data);
$user->usersVideogames()->sync($data['videojuegos_tienen_usuarios'] ?? []);
});
return redirect()
->route('admin.videojuegos.users)
->with('statusType', 'success')
->with('statusMessage', 'The videogames were updated.');
} catch(\Exception $e) {
return redirect()
->route('admin.videojuegos.usuarios', ['id' => $id])
->with('statusType', 'danger')
->with('statusMessage', 'Error.')
->withInput();
}
}
```

**Videogame Model**

```
protected $table = 'videogames';
protected $primaryKey = 'videogames_id';
protected $fillable = ['plataforma_id', 'titulo', 'subtitulo', 'precio', 'fecha_estreno', 'sinopsis', 'contenido' , 'portada', 'portada_juego', 'portada_descripcion', 'categoria_id', 'numjugadores_id', 'img_descripcion'];

public function users()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(
User::class,
'videojuegos_tienen_usuarios',
'videogames_id',
'user_id',
'videogames_id',
'user_id',
);
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function usersVideogames()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Videogames::class, 'usuarios_tienen_videojuegos', 'user_id', 'videogames_id');
}

public function getGameId(): array
{
return $this->videogames->pluck('videogames_id')->toArray();
}
```

**HTML**

I’m displaying the games selected by the user, but what I’m trying to do is to display all the videogames and show the selected inputs with the videogames selected by the user.

```
@foreach($user->usersVideogames as $game)
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
<input
type="checkbox"
name="videogames[]"
value="{{ $game->videogames_id }}"
@checked($user->usersVideogames)
>
<label for="game-{{ $game->videogames_id }}" class="form-check-label">{{ $game->subtitle }}</label>
</div>
@endforeach

<button type="submit">Update Games</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get from DB list of all games and then check is it contains games prefered by user:

```
// $games - collection of all games
@foreach($games as $game)
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="videogames[]"
    value="{{ $game->videogames_id }}"
    @checked($user->usersVideogames->contains($game))
    >
    <label for="game-{{ $game->videogames_id }}" class="form-check-label">{{ $game->subtitle }}</label>
  </div>
@endforeach

<button type="submit">Update Games</button>
```

Comment: Such a small change in the line code haha Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
// first build an array of the selected video game id's
// this should be in the controller or model depending on your framework

$selected_games = [];
foreach ($user->usersVideogames as $game) {
    $selected_games[] = $game->videogames_id;
}

// then you can loop over all the games and check the 
// ones that are selected by the user
// $videogames equals all the video games you offer

@foreach ($videogames as $game)     
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="videogames[]"
            value="{{ $game->videogames_id }}"
            {{ in_array($game->videogames_id, $selected_games) ? ' checked' : '' }}
            >
            <label for="game-{{ $game->videogames_id }}" 
            class="form-check-label">{{ $game->subtitle }}</label>
        </div>  
@endforeach
```

Comment: You don't need to create another array/collection with selected games, you can simply check is collection has value while iterating data

Comment: I agree, not sure what framework he is using though. Maybe best for him to do it the easy way to get it working then improve later. I wish I knew for sure what framework he was using.

Comment: There is `Laravel` tag :)

Comment: If that is the case then I agree with you 100% on the use of $user->usersVideogames->contains($game)
I do see him using a blade template and thought it was laravel but not quite sure.

Comment: Hi! yes, I'm using Laravel. Thanks for your help